# Rails scope returns duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

I have a Rails scope query that is returning duplicates. Can anyone see what's the problem with it?
Here's the code:

```
scope :visible_to_user, lambda { |user|
 {
  :joins      => 'LEFT JOIN SCHEMA.groups ON groups.id = uploaded_files.group_id
                  LEFT JOIN uploaded_file_references ON uploaded_files.id = uploaded_file_references.uploaded_file_id
                  LEFT JOIN message_threads ON message_threads.id = uploaded_file_references.thread_id
                  LEFT JOIN thread_participants ON thread_participants.message_thread_id = message_threads.id',
  :conditions => [
    %{
        uploaded_files.in_private_conversation = false
        AND ( ( NOT COALESCE(groups.private, false) ) 
              OR uploaded_files.group_id IN (?) 
              OR ( thread_participants.referenced_id = '?' 
                   AND thread_participants.referenced_type = 'User')          
            )
    }, user.group_ids, user.id
  ]
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In rails >= 3:
You can add .uniq call to any scope to not return duplicates, like so:

```
MyTable.a_scope.where(something).uniq
```

In rails < 3:
you have to add it by hand with a select configuration like so:

```
MyTable.find(:all, :select => "distinct my_table.*")
```

Comment: That didn't work. I got the following exception: ArgumentError (Unknown key(s): unique):

Comment: Sorry, I though rails 2.3 had that functionality. I updated the answer to include the rails 2.3 way of doing what you need.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough when I posted the question, but my first choice would be to fix the query itself rather than adding a call to uniq everywhere in the code.

Comment: Well, that's how sql works... If you have more than one record on the joined tables per record of the main table, you'll have duplicates